# IIS redirect wildcard few subdomain to domain

Tags: iis, redirect, url-rewriting, iis-8

I have problem with redirect.
I have domain like:
example.com
and a few subdomain like
application.example.com
documents.example.com

It's hard to make a wildcard binding, so i want to do URL redirect in Default Web Site ;)
If somebody make mistake in URL address like:
doduments.example.com - I want to redirect him to example.com

Here the case is more complicated, because i need do something similar, but for another domain:
example.pl
and subdomains
aplikacja.example.pl
dokumenty.example.pl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this ;)

```
            <rule name="*.example.pl" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example\.pl$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.pl/" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="*.example2.pl" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example2\.pl$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://example2.pl/" />
            </rule>
```

Far from perfection, but it works.
I won't be able to filter domain in match url - i don't know why ;(